# what android permissions required for deep link in versions 12 and 13

Tags: android-12, android-deep-link

deep links URls are not working for android 12 and 13 working expected upto 11 version devices.

I did autoverify= true in intent  and signature is matching with the the website wellknown folder.  what permissions should use for deep link work in android 12 and 13. and is it true that in android 12 deep link works in production mode after match the signature.